# If $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, show that if $A \neq 0$ then $\exists x \in \Bbb R^n$ such that $Ax \neq 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ matrix. Show that if $A \neq 0$ then $\exists x \in  \Bbb R^n$ such that $Ax \neq 0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

$A \neq 0 \Rightarrow $ there exists a i-th column $A_i$ in $A$  that is not equal $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

$A\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{pmatrix}=A_i \neq 0$